# Moving transparent 2D image in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

I'd like to implement moving 2D image with transparency (alpha is not necessary, but would be nice) moving above another image in .NET Form.

I tried to override Panel

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams {
    get {
        CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
        cp.ExStyle |= 0x00000020; //WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
        return cp;
    }
}
```

and `Invalidate()` after move, but the performance is not good. Should I use DirectX, OpenGL or some game framework like XNA? A code snippet or link to some tutorial would be useful. It should be

- easy to implement (as little extra code as possible)
- fast and efficient

Comment: If You want to animate images You should probably use a dedicated framework or library. If You can't or don't want to use any library for some reason, maybe You could try to paint the images on a `PictureBox` control and handle this manually (it's better for painting than `Panel`). It depends on a specific case, but using separate control for each image may not be good from performance perspective. Please also consider using WPF, as it seems to be better suited for graphically rich and animated interfaces than WinForms, like mentioned in the answer posted by *Kimmax*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Winforms wasn't made for this kind of stuff. You could try WPF, but I would recommand to use a framework if you wan't good graphic implentation.

Comment: WPF uses DirectX, which is approx. 10x faster on my comp. Thanks for pushing me into right direction.